# Gaussian heat kernel bounds on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation

I wish to know if we have Gaussian lower and upper bounds for the heat kernel,i.e. $$
t^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{\rho(x,y)^2}{C_1t}} \lesssim p_t(x,y) \lesssim  t^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{\rho(x,y)^2}{C_2t}},
$$
on a compact Riemannian manifold. If this is not true in full generality, may be it is true with curvature restrictions? I would appreciate a reference.

More generally, one could ask under what sorts of sufficient conditions two-sided estimates like the above hold on complete Riemannian manifolds near the diagonal. I know that two-sided off-diagonal Gaussian estimates hold on complete Riemannian manifolds with non-negative Ricci curvature, but I was hoping that in assuming $x \sim y$, we could relax the curvature restrictions substantially.

Edit: This is answered pretty well at [Sharp Gaussian upper bounds on Heat Kernel](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168438/sharp-gaussian-upper-bounds-on-heat-kernel) (see Sebastian Goette's comment below).

Comment: Welcome to MO. Your question is pretty close to [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/q/168438/70808) and some others. If you are not satisfied with the answers over there, please edit your question and add the information you would like to see.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thanks, the answer you linked to has more or less everything I need.