# Heat kernel asymptotics for small distances

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry

I heard a talk where the speaker said that on a Riemannian manifold, for small values of $\text{dist }(x, y)$, the heat kernel $p_t(x, y)$ satisfies 
$$p_t(x, y) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{\text{dist }(x, y)^2}{4t}} + O(e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}).$$

Is this correct? Where can I find a reference for this fact? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The original reference should be the paper by Molchanov "Diffusion processes and Riemannian geometry". You can find a pdf here (in russian):

http://www.mathnet.ru/links/74671d2aaeb444f56a570dddcce7e644/rm4123.pdf

and the english translation here:

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1975v030n01ABEH001400/meta

Answer (score 2):

I think a good reference is "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators"
by Nicole Berline, Ezra Getzler, Michèle Vergne, page 61.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot locate it on page 61. Could you please tell me what edition you are using? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The one in Google Books: https://books.google.cz/books?id=_e2FjvLbO94C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Okay, it was page 63 in the edition I could find. But I still don't understand why the expansion that we get for $p_t(x, y) - \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{\text{dist }(x, y)^2}{4t}} $ is actually $O(e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}).$  Is it obvious? I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: @user85970 Sorry, I'm not an expert. You may find closely related discussion in this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168438/sharp-gaussian-upper-bounds-on-heat-kernel/199388#199388